# npapi wrap multi control

Tags: activex, npapi, browser-plugin

I want to wrap some `activex dll` to `npapi`. An `ActiveX DLL` can contain many controls, just like the one I'm going to wrap.

Can a `npapi dll` contain many controls? I know the `npapi` control is working like:

```
x-application/x-...
```

It just seems that the `npapi dll` can't wrap many controls, so I must split the controls in the `activex dll`, but I don't think it's a good idea because there are some public data structs.

Is it possible to have a `npapi dll` with multiple controls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NPAPI plugins can support multiple mimetypes and all popular plugins actually have more than one (check e.g. `about:plugins` in Firefox).

The places where you specify the mimetypes for your plugins all support specifying multiple ones.
[`NPP_New()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/NPP_New) and [`NPP_NewStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/NPP_NewStream) receive a `NPMIMEType` parameter that you can check.